# Get a part of that String C#

Tags: c#, string, irc

```
:barbosza!barbosza@barbosza.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #pggamesbr :My text
```

I want the part after the second ':', but i can't split by ':' because sometimes  contains it too.

Comment: Consider using `LastIndexOf` and `Substring` based on that

Comment: If it's the last one you want have you investigated the `LastIndexOf` method?

Comment: I think OP means that the actual message could contain `:`, in which case you'd probably want the first index (assuming you remove the first character).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split and specify the maximum number of items, so that everything after the second colon ends up in the third item:

```
string[] parts = str.Split(new char[]{':'}, 3);
```

The part after the second colon is now in `parts[2]`.

Comment: Neat, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that "he contains it too" means "My text contains it too".

In that case, do this

```
string toFind = "#pggamesbr :";
string myText = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(toFind) + toFind.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Guffa's simple `Split` solution, and would go with that if this is all you need here.  But, just for fun...

If you run into a lot of odd cases like this -- things you wish were easier to do with strings -- you can consider adding extension methods to handle them.  E.g.,

```
using System;

public static MyStringExtentions
{
    public static string After(this string orig, char delimiter)
    {
        int p = orig.indexOf(delimiter);
        if (p == -1)
            return string.Empty;
        else
            return orig.Substring(p + 1);
    }
}
```

And then, in your existing code, as long as you have a `using` directive to include reference access to `MyStringExtentions`'s definition:

```
string afterPart = myString.After(':').After(':');
```

*Disclaimer: I didn't actually test this.  Some tuning may be required.  And it could probably be tuned to be more efficient, etc.*

Again, this is probably overkill for this one problem.  (See Guffa's perfectly good simple answer for that.)  Just tossing it out for when you find yourself with lots of these and want a common way to make them available.

*Ref. [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)*